# tomee mvn install don't pack META-INF

Tags: maven, apache-tomee, meta-inf

When trying to build war file maven doesn't pack any META-INF using pom:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>demo-test</groupId>
<artifactId>core-parent</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<name>test</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <test.core.version>1.0.0</test.core.version>
</properties>

<modules>
    <module>testDataModule</module>
    <module>testFramework</module>
    <module>testManagerModule</module>
    <module>CoreWar</module>
</modules>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <!-- scope provided means the container delivers it -->
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>test</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.openejb.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomee-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>test</finalName>
                <tomeeVersion>1.5.2</tomeeVersion>
                <tomeeClassifier>plus</tomeeClassifier>
                <path>C:\test\code\test.core\CoreWar\target\test.war</path>
                <debug>true</debug>
                <tomeeHost>localhost</tomeeHost>
                <tomeeHttpPort>8080</tomeeHttpPort>
                <libs>
                    <lib>mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.20</lib>
                </libs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <webXml>..\testFramework\WebFramework\src\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
                <outputFileNameMapping>@{groupId}@-@{artifactId}@@{dashClassifier?}@.@{extension}@</outputFileNameMapping>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and I tried puting META-INF everywhere.
and don't replace tomee.xml
I tried the following structure:

myApp->src->resources->meta-inf/persistence.xml
myApp->src->webapp->meta-inf/persistence.xml

Answer (score 0):

did you try webapp/WEB-INF/persistence.xml?